# Google drive folder on laptop says 13.3 GB used whereas google drive online says 30GB

Tags: storage, google-drive, cloud-storage, google-cloud-storage

I'm sure there is a solution to this problem but I can't seem to find the answer

I have a google drive account. When I look at the properties of the google drive folder on my laptop it says it is 13.3 GB in size (see below)

[image]

However, when I go to google drive online it says I have used 30.6 GB.

[image]

This is a pretty large discrepancy!

Can anyone tell me (a) why this is happening, and (b) how to fix it.

Comment: My guess would be that the size of the folder on your laptop doesn't reflect the size of what you have in google drive.  My guess would be that It only reflects what google has synch'ed with your machine.  This is the only logical reason that I can see for what you are experiencing.  Perhaps someone else will chime in. :)

Comment: Also.. google drive, dropbox, OneDrive, etc.. they fake everything on the local machine and represent themselves through explorer shell extensions.  What they choose to cache is up to them (and not you).. they don't reflect real numbers necessarily.  You might see a file in there.. and when you click on it, it gets copied to the local machine and wasn't there to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is shown on your desktop version is only what is in that synced folder on the desktop.

With the Google web browser view, it is showing all of your Google Drive storage. Your Google Drive storage consists of Gmail, Photos (photos that are uploaded in original quality) and Google Drive.

If you click on "Buy Storage" then scroll to the top of the page it links you to, you'll be able to see how much you're storage you're using for each application.

It's also important to note that whatever is in the trash on Google Drive, still counts towards your storage until it's deleted after 30 days from its original deletion date.

If everything in your trash is for sure ready to be deleted, you can delete it manually to reclaim that space now.

If you have any photos that are taking up space, you can convert them from original quality to high quality to reclaim that space as well.

Google Photos is ending its unlimited free storage on June 1st, 2021. Any photos that are converted from original quality to high quality before then, will not count towards your data cap. If you have a Google Pixel phone, you'll still be able to upload high quality images for free, after June 1st.